# socket.io client events not firing

Tags: socket.io

According to the [docs][1]

[1]: http://socket.io/docs/client-api/, the following events should be firing on the client when connecting, error and disconnecting etc:

- connect. Fired upon connecting.
- error. Fired upon a connection error
- disconnect. Fired upon a disconnection.
- reconnect. Fired upon a
  successful reconnection.

How do I listen to this socket events on the client? I am using the following but events are not being fired:

```
var socket = io.connect(); // does connect fine
socket.on('connect', function() {
   console.log('connect fired');
});
```

Comment: Does your console print 'connect fired' on connection? If it doesn't then it means your client is having problems in connecting with server

Comment: Turn out it works fine on chrome and safari, but not firefox

Comment: May be the version of your firefox doesn't support web sockets